# How to convert scanned .tiff files into editable LaTeX files

Tags: pdftex

I'm new to LaTeX platform and got trained just 1 day on TeX commands 2 days before, my TL rushing me to finish 50 pages per day but I can do only 7 pages a day, what I'm doing is entering each and every words from scanned `.tiff` image file in TeX editor, so it taking huge time. Can anyone please help me to fine some smart working tools to reduce my huge manual work.

Comment: First of all look for an OCR tool to turn the tables content into text that can be copied and pasted. That should already be a big time saver; together with some regex-based search&replace you might be able to transform this int a raw LaTex table. If not, The next step then would be a tool to copy and paste complete tables, maybe to some Office tool as an intermediate step. Acrobat has a good OCR engine an can, AFAIK, export to Word or Excel. With tools like `excel2latex` it might be possible to get a half-complete LaTeX table.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my suggestions:

**Convert locally**

If you are on Windows:

1. Download and install [Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/) and its plug in modules.
2. Download and install [Pdf-Xchange viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer). remember to install the correct OCR modules
3. Use `Irfanview` to batch convert your .TIF files into .PDF
4. Open the PDF-document in PDF-xchange viewer and OCR it. Mark the text you want and paste it into  your LaTeX editor

**Online solution**

1. Go to [NewOCR.com](http://www.newocr.com/).
2. Upload your .TIF-files and convert it to text.
3. Copy and paste the converted text into your editor